# excel- group and concatenate cells (in varying number of rows) under each serial number

Tags: excel, concatenation

I've an excel file as given below

---

```
1    word1     MEANING1.1          meaning1.1
               MEANING1.2

2    word2     MEANING2.1          meaning2.1
               MEANING2.2          meaning2.2
                                   meaning2.3

3    word3     MEANING3.1          meaning3.1

4    word4     MEANING4.1          meaning4.1
               MEANING4.2          meaning4.2
               MEANING4.3
               MEANING4.4
```

I need to concatenate the meanings across each word, to get an output like below

---

```
1      word1      MEANING1.1,MEANING1.2   meaning1.1
2      word2      MEANING2.1,MEANING2.2   meaning2.1,meaning2.2,meaning2.3
3      word3      MEANING3.1              meaning3.1
4      word4      MEANING4.1,MEANING4.2...meaning4.1,meaning4.2
```

Can anyone please help me to make a formula for this?

Thanks

Comment: Would doing this manually using the formula =CONCATENATE() be an option? If so look [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010062562.aspx) for a description of it.

Comment: Forgot to add, I've a few thousand such 'words' in my file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of steps. First create a new column that populates as the word so it is always filled.

```
D1 = A1
if(A2 = 0,D1,A2)
.
.
.
```

Next create another new column with a numeric count of how many meanings there are.

```
E1 = 1
if(E2 = 0,E1+1,1)
.
.
.
```

Next create a pivot table of the column MEANING, meaning and the new word column from above.

Using the sides of the pivot table, make it so you get WORD, MEANING where the numeric column is 1; copy paste out to new sheet
Repeat until max number of MEANINGs; copying them into new columns each time
Repeat with meanings
Use concatenate function to Add it all together in the right format.

Answer (score 2):

I happened to already have a custom function for this.  Paste this code in a module in your workbook:

```
Public Function ConcatenateRange(r As Range, Optional DeLim As String) As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim str As String

    Application.Volatile True

    For Each c In r.Cells

        str = str & DeLim & c

    Next

    ConcatenateRange = str
End Function
```

Then use this formula in a cell:

`=ConcatenateRange("The range you want to combine", ",")`

Comment: a simple fix to make perfect: just after the loop (a row below NEXT), add this command: str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1). This way DeLim won't be the first character

Comment: Small fix - the command should only be invoked if **DeLim** is not an empty string: **If (DeLim <> "") Then str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)**